# Android Network Programming: IOExceptions and StackOverflowError

Tags: android, networking, ioexception, stack-overflow

In my Android app, I try to connect to a port on a local server to get some packets. I've encased to code in some try & catch's but with the following code:

```
address = "192.168.175.82";
public void run() {
    try {
  smtpSocket = new Socket(address, 60001);

        os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + address);
        run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + address);
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("retry");
     run();
    }
```

if ther server is not on, I obviously get the IOException a few times (e.g. a few hundred times) before I get a stack overflow error and the app crashes.

```
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678): java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:282)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:177)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:440)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:412)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Boolean.java:174)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.NetUtil$Action.run(NetUtil.java:89)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.NetUtil$Action.run(NetUtil.java:80)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedImpl(AccessController.java:264)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:84)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.NetUtil.preferIPv6Addresses(NetUtil.java:51)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:777)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:192)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:256)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:220)
01-20 22:21:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5678):     at com.example.sockets.ReadSocket.run(ReadSocket.java:83)
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction of how to get this to work? Perhaps I should test the connection first somehow (if so, please say how?)
Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, drop the recursive call. This will get rid of the stack overflow.
Replace it with a loop and sleep in each unsuccessful iteration

```
  public void run() {
     boolean connected = false;  
     while(!connected)
     {
     try {
      smtpSocket = new Socket(address, 60001);

            os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());


      connected = true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + address);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + address);

        } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("retry");

        }
        if (!connected)
            Thread.sleep(1000)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks. Just figured this out as you posted! Excuse my idiotic-ness =P.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `isConnected()` and [`isBound()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#isBound%28%29) on your socket to check wether you are connected or not before trying to get an inputstream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, doing this still causes the overflow error. I even tried removing the i/o streams altogether but the error persisted.

Comment: the 2 method return true???
because if they don't, you can change your handling, or set a delay before repeating the attempt to connect?